# Magento: Storeview Access

Tags: magento, access-control

**Situation right now:**

I've got a live-system and its running very well.
I DO NOT have a testing system.

Our live-system is a multi-store with several storeviews on one website.

**PROBLEM:**

I need to to add one more storeview and work on that within that livesystem. How can I restrict access to this storeview, so that no customer, whether logged in or not, can see this store? Is this even possible?

I need just an admin (me) to access this storeview.

Sure, I could disable all storeswitcher in the other live-stores but I don't think, this would be a nice solution to my problem. :)

Comment: its obvious, set up a development site

Comment: and what about merging the databases? I don't want to loose any orders or customers.

Comment: dude you don't need a uptodate database to for developing. Usually it goes like this that you have dev, staging and live sites. You only merge databases from live to dev and stage and never from dev  to stage to live. Every setup you make you do with setup scripts with modules thats how you can keep your site and codebase free of limits and restorable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to show up currently edited store (view) on your language dropdown select field, do the following:

1. Add a new customer-group called "admins" to your shop and remember the id which appears in the list.
2. If not already done, add a new customer for the admin and assign it to the just created customer-group
3. Go to system->store-view and click on the link in the StoreView Name - column which you dont want to show up on the frontend and klick it, you'll see the StoreView id in the url /index.php/admin/system_store/editStore/store_id/**3**/key/, remember it
4. Now edit the file: app/design/frontend/default/your_shop/template/page/switch/languages.phtml

from:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Your Language:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php 
// StoreView-Ids we dont want to show on frontend
$stores = array(3);
// Set admin group id with access to the above storeviews
$frontendAdminGroupId = 5; 
// Get current user group id
$currentGroupId = $this->helper('customer')->getCurrentCustomer()->group_id;
?>
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Your Language:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>   
        <?php foreach ($stores as $_adminStore) : ?>            
            <?php /* Admin Store! */?>
            <?php if($_adminStore == $_lang->getId() ) : ?>
                <?php if($currentGroupId == $frontendAdminGroupId) : ?> 
                    <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
            <?php /* Normal User! */?>
                 <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you also have to edit the checkout and any other part of magento which shows up a select field for the store view, that's just a half solution. good luck :-)

Comment: This doesn't actually prevent access at all, and doesn't answer the OP's question. It just removes references to the other store on the frontend. If an unwanted user knew the URL to hit, they could still access the site.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Magento Enterprise you are given a staging site where you would be able to make these changes before pushing them out to production.

Or, you can do as @Anton S above said and create a development site. You would use Magento's export functionality to move changes over. NOT a full database dump/import. That way you won't lose any customer and order information.